# Shapely for pixel geometry

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, shapely

I'm using the `shapely` library to handle my geometry-based computation. However, I'm working with integer geometry (such as pixels), which unfortunately means the `shapely` computations are off-by-one. For instance, normally this is the expected result:

```
>>> import shapely
>>> mp = shapely.MultiPoint([(1,1), (2,2)])
>>> shapely.box(*mp.bounds).area
1.0
```

However, with pixel geometry, this rectangle should have an area of 4 (since it contains the pixels `(1,1)`, `(1,2)`, `(2,1)`, `(2,2)`).

I tried to fix this by subclassing `MultiPoint`:

```
class Cluster(shapely.MultiPoint):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        if not all(all(isinstance(c, int) for c in coord) for coord in self):
            raise ValueError("Cluster coordinates must be integers.")

    @property
    def bounds(self):
        bounds = super().bounds
        return bounds[0], bounds[1], bounds[2] + 1, bounds[3] + 1
```

However, this didn't seem  to do anything, as even `bounds` is still printing the same thing:

```
>>> c = Cluster([(1,1), (2,2)]) 
>>> c.bounds
(1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0)
>>> shapely.box(*c.bounds).area
1.0
```

Also, pylint is warning me that the methods `coords` and `xy` are abstract but not implemented in my class, which makes no sense to me, since `MultiPoint` can be instantiated, so it shouldn't contain any unimplemented abstract methods.

Is there a `shapely` alternative that handles pixel geometry? Alternatively, why is my overridden `bounds` property not returning the values I want?

Comment: You are using MultiPoint. That is a collection of individual Points which is a Line. This is not an area. When you call area you get a unit less dimension which in this case represents length. You will want to use Polygon with 4 point or you can use shapely.box to get the square bounding box from a Polygon.

Comment: You can absolutely use shapely for pixel geometry and, in fact, it's very well suited for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, the way `shapely` is written some classes are not particularly subclass-friendly. `MultiPoint`, for instance, only defines `__new__` and not `__init__` for new object instantiation, which makes it much more difficult to subclass properly.

As such, I ended up making a wrapper class instead:

```
from collections.abc import Set
import functools as ft
import numpy as np
import shapely


class Cluster(Set):
    off_by_one = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])

    def __init__(self, points=None, **kw):
        if points is not None and not all(all(isinstance(coord, int) for coord in p) for p in points):
            raise ValueError("Cluster coordinates must be integers.")
        self.points = shapely.MultiPoint(points, **kw)

    def __contains__(self, point):
        return shapely.Point(point) in self.points.geoms

    def __iter__(self):
        for p in self.points.geoms:
            yield p.x, p.y

    @ft.lru_cache(maxsize=1024)  # I don't ever expect more than 1024 clusters
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.points.geoms)

    def __or__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, type(self)):
            return type(self)(self.points | other.points)
        if isinstance(other, shapely.MultiPoint):
            return type(self)(self.points | other)
        return NotImplemented
    __ror__ = __or__

    def __and__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, type(self)):
            return type(self)(self.points & other.points)
        if isinstance(other, shapely.MultiPoint):
            return type(self)(self.points & other)
        return NotImplemented
    __rand__ = __and__

    # We don't define __ior__ and __iand__ because they would invalidate the cached values

    @ft.cached_property
    def bounds(self):
        return self.points.bounds + self.off_by_one

    @ft.cached_property
    def area(self):
        return int(shapely.box(*self.bounds).area)

    @ft.cached_property
    def density(self):
        return len(self) / self.area

    @classmethod
    def neighbours(cls, c1, c2):
        """
        Check if two `Cluster`s are neighbours.

        The `Cluster`s are considered neighbours if their bounding boxes overlap or touch (a corner touch is enough).
        """
        return shapely.box(*c1.bounds).intersects(shapely.box(*c2.bounds))
```

This now works as I wanted it to:

```
>>> c = Cluster([(1,1), (2,2)])
>>> c.area
4
>>> c.density
0.5
```